# Is it possible to determine a string's width in Appcelerator?

Tags: string, appcelerator

I'm trying to determine the length of a String so I can dynamically layout some Labels. In iOS I would use:
`CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:font];`
Is it possible to do this with the Appcelerator API or is there another way to do this type of dynamic layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    'layout': 'horizontal'
});
```

https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/horizontal_layout.js

Comment: layout: 'horizontal' was the key. Thanks, missed that one in the Kitchen Sink.

Answer (score 1):

If you create labels with 'auto' width, once they've been constructed you can access their actual width and position any other labels accordingly:

```
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: 'This is a test string',
    width: 'auto',
    color: '#FFF',
    left: 0,
    top: 0
});

var labelWidth = label.width;

Ti.API.info(labelWidth);

// Dynamically position the second label
var secondLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: 'Second label',
    width: 100,
    left: labelWidth + 10,
    top: 0,
    color: '#FFF'
});

window.add(label);
window.add(secondLabel);

window.open();
```

It's not very elegant but it works.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me. It's getting logged as 'auto' and the second label is being drawn on top of the first. I should have mentioned that I'm trying this with mobilesdk 1.7 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad example - though the principle is sound. I've updated the example code, try that - the version shouldn't make a difference, I'm using 1.6.2 though.

Comment: This is probably because you need add the labels to the windows before laying them out.

Comment: Nevertheless I have issues with that, too. Appcelerator can be finicky.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'd only used it on the iPhone when I answered, good to know!